# Get the first created user per organization

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT email, org_id, MIN(created_at) as first_user_created
FROM users
WHERE org_id IN (SELECT org_id FROM subscriptions)
GROUP BY email, org_id;
```

Result of the above query gives me multiple user records per org_id.

What I want: Per organization - return the `email`, `org_id` and `first_user_created` of user that got created the earliest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution uses `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.org_id) u.email, u.org_id, u.created_at
FROM users u
INNER JOIN subscriptions s
    ON s.org_id = u.org_id
ORDER BY u.org_id, u.created_at;
```

Another way to do this uses `RANK()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT u.email, u.org_id, u.created_at,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY u.org_id ORDER BY u.created_at) rnk
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN subscriptions s ON s.org_id = u.org_id
)

SELECT email, org_id, created_at
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Both solution only returns one user record, the very earliest user that got created. Is it possible to expand on this and apply the earliest user that got created per org_id?

Comment: Check the updated answer.  I didn't see any sample data in your question, and so it seems I interpreted what you wanted wrongly.